# Security on Android

Tags: java, security, ssl, netty, httpserver

Hello I am a student trying to build a server for my android application.

I am making an application something like Facebook.

My server's framework is Netty and I am using HTTP.

So my question is,

1. Why is security important when in Android?

I know that this may be a trivial question, but isn't ID and Password good enough for security?(especially on android?)

1. If I really need someting like SSL or TLS, what would be the lifecycle of communication. (From logging in to sending a POST request with some file)

Answer (score 1):

> Why is security important when in Android?

That question the requirements of your project that should answer. If your application has sensitive data is important to have a minimum of security in your application. Not only in the application as it should contain the same rule on your server. Data encryption on both sides is important to prevent information theft.

> If I really need someting like SSL or TLS, what would be the lifecycle of communication. (From logging in to sending a POST request with some file)

As the data are not sufficient to maintain the security of the information in your application, especially in that there are many android malware that can easily retrieve this information and use it the way he wants. Nowadays, the platform with the most impact Android malware is about [99% of mobile malware targets the android](http://www.kaspersky.com/about/news/virus/2013/99_of_all_mobile_threats_target_Android_devices). Android has simple tools for SSL communication, see the [link](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html).

So, If the loss of data from your application has a significant impact worth investing safely to avoid hassles in the future.